# How to save tuples output form for loop to DataFrame Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some data 33k rows x 57 columns.

In some columns there is a data which I want to translate with dictionary.
I have done translation, but now I want to write back translated data to my data set.

I have problem with saving tuples output from for loop.

I am using tuples for creating good translation.  `.join` and `.append` is not working in my case. I was trying in many case but without any success.
Looking for any advice.

```py
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, engine="python", sep=";", keep_default_na=False)

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    row["translated"] = (tuple(slownik.get(znak) for znak in row["1st_service"]))
```

I just want to see in `print(data["1st_service"]` a translated data not the previous one before for loop.

Comment: Can you add a short example of your data frame?

Comment: it is a data showing each point in a game, point by point (row by row)

Comment: Before translation in a cell is like ab8@c ——> after translation I get a word for each symbol. So for this will be like ‘wide’ ‘middle’ ‘leftside’ ‘Big’ ‘top’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if your csv doesn't already have a 'translated' column, you'll have to add it:

```
import numpy as np
data['translated'] = np.nan
```

The problem is the `row` object you're trying to write to is only a view of the dataframe, it's not the dataframe itself. Plus you're missing square brackets for your list comprehension, if I'm understanding what you're doing. So change your last line to:

```
data.loc[index, "translated"] = tuple([slownik.get(znak) for znak in row["1st_service"]])
```

and you'll get a tuple written into that one cell.

In future, posting the exact error message you're getting is very helpful!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was trying to fix my code but I have such an error:
    `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Answer (score 0):

I have manage it, below working code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, engine="python", sep=";", keep_default_na=False)

data.columns = []

slownik = dict([    ])


trans = ' '
for index, row in data.iterrows():
   trans += str(tuple([slownik.get(znak) for znak in row["1st_service"]]))

data['1st_service'] = trans.split(')(')

data.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Can you tell me if it is well done?
Maybe there is an faster way to do it?
I am doing it for 12 columns in one for loop, as shown up.